# Google Chrome CSS/rendering bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, render

Here is my website: [link text](http://www.ipalaces.org)

On my website, it seems every updated browser (FF, Opera, Safari, IE8, IE7, and even IE6) seem to render the separating line between my content div and sideMenu div.

However, chrome browser doesn't seem to want to render the background to the container div ([link text](http://www.ipalaces.org/files/images/containerbg.gif)) where the content div is. It seems like my content div is one pixel to the left too much. However, when you zoom the text (Ctrl + Scrollwheel) the line will appear.

Is this a known rendering bug? or a CSS bug?

Here is my website: [link text](http://www.ipalaces.org)

Comment: I see no difference between browsers.

Comment: I am using chrome 3.

For some reason google chrome reads my css background "mainbg.gif" wrong if the width is over 862. Anything less than 862 then there will be a divider between my sideMenu and content DIVs. Anything more than 862 and it wont show the divider, its like chrome is stretching the picture or messing with something.

Comment: Can you post the section of the code and the css rules to which you are referring. You description is vague, I'm not sure what you mean by the container div or the content div. I shouldn't have to read your question then go to your website and view source just to answer your question. 

I see no difference between Chrome and Firefox' rendering of this. Also, Safari and Chrome both use Webkit to render webpages, as such it seem quite strange that it renders correctly on Safari but not Chrome. 

You can use http://browsershots.org/ to look at snapshots of your web page in different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glitch might go away if you remove "background: #FFF;" from your #content css. The part of the background image that's beneath the content div is white anyways.